Stacked ybar plot in tikz but with log scale on the y axis
I am trying to make a stacked ybar plot using tikz. While I am able to do that, it results in a very uninformative plot (can't post images because I don't have enough reputation)
Inital plot
The MWE to produce this image is as follows:
\documentclass[preprint,12pt, 3p, sort&compress]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}

\pgfplotsset{
  log y ticks with fixed point/.style={
      yticklabel={
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}
        \pgfmathparse{exp(\tick)}%
        \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed relative, precision=3]{\pgfmathresult}
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
      }
  }
}

% Data
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,header=true]{
M,A,B,C,D,E,F,G
0,1500000,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,300,0,0,0,0,50
2,0,0,1000000,0,50000,0,0
3,0,0,0,10000,0,500,50
}\data

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar stacked,
             ymin = 0,
             ylabel = Time (in seconds),
             xtick = {0, 1, 2, 3},
             xlabel style = {font=\small},
             ylabel style = {font=\small},
             yticklabel style = {font=\small},
             xticklabel style = {font=\small}]
  \addplot table[x=M,y=A] from \data;
  \addplot table[x=M,y=B] from \data;
  \addplot table[x=M,y=C] from \data;
  \addplot table[x=M,y=D] from \data;
  \addplot table[x=M,y=E] from \data;
  \addplot table[x=M,y=F] from \data;
  \addplot table[x=M,y=G] from \data;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

I would like to make the y axis log scale, so that the information and multiple stacks are more clear. Trying ymode = log does make it happen (to some extent) but I see two issues: one, that the plot is still not how I would want it to be, and second, log(0) in my data is actually giving errors (understandably so). I get the same result using semilogyaxis. Previously, at least the stacks were joined together as I would expect but using log somehow distances them.
Log attempt
What I would want is a y axis starting from 100 up until 107, and all the stacked bars starting from 100 with no vertical spaces between then. How would I go about achieving this? That way I can show the tall stack on index 0, and also show the contribution of two stacks on index 1 that would eventual amount to 350.
